# Awstats - the 'HTTP Status codes' information is missing. How to fix?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, awstats

I'm trying to configure Awstats for a website on Centos 7.

Currently everything works fine (I can see stats, keywords, page hits, etc.), but there's a section on Awstats that reads "HTTP Status codes" and under that header there are some codes like 404, 301, etc.

I can click the link and I can open the page for each status code, however the list is empty, for all HTTP codes.

When I open the logs for my website I can see the 404's being recorded in there.

Why are they not being displayed on Awstats? What could be wrong?

[image]

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Comment: Are they missing for just the current year? I have this same issue, but the numbers appear for years and months that are fully in the past. Just the current incomplete month and year are missing.